# JSON Dictionary return __NSCFNumber class for NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using below code to get class of number run time

```
 NSDecimalNumber* decimalNumber;

if ([paymentOrderDetail[@"Total"] class]==[NSNumber class]) {

decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[paymentOrderDetail[@"Total"] stringValue]];

}else{

    decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:paymentOrderDetail[@"Total"]];
}
```

If condition always fail even if the total is a Number not string, when I printed the total class its giving "__NSCFNumber"

But I am not able to compare it with "__NSCFNumber"

Is there any way by which I can know the class type of the total object

Comment: Why dont you try `isKindOfClass` on  `paymentOrderDetail[@"Total"]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSNumber` is a cluster class and can incapsulate different representations for different data types. You should use `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]` method to check type of the object.

Here you can read more about cluster classes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Comment: There are _lots_ of class clusters. You should never expect any object to have the class that it has "officially".

Comment: @gnasher729 so should i use or not [obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ??? because its working in my case is it not preferred ?

Comment: I recommend you to use isKindOfClass everywhere.

Comment: I thought that would be clear. Do what Mikhail said. And never expect that a method returning say an NSString* returns an object of class [NSString class] etc. Not just for NSNumber. And for example NSJSONSerialization will often return NSDecimalNumber anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` method will only work, if the instance is of the same class ONLY. It will not work even when you have a child class which extends from a superclass. In such scenarios use `isKindOfClass` method.

> E.g. Suppose you have the following scenario of classes.

```
Superclass: Vehicle
Subclass: Car, Van, Bus

Car *c = [[Car alloc] init];

if([c class] == [Vehicle class]) // This will **Fail**

if([c isKindOfClass:[Vehicle class]]) //This will **Succeed**
```

> Now, take the following scenario comparing two Car objects.

```
Car c2 = [[Car alloc] init];

if([c class] == [c2 class]) // This will now **Succeed**

if([c isKindOfClass:[c2 class]]) //This will also **Succeed**
```